# Inner matrix dimensions must agree error and how to setup separate arrays based on frequency response data?

Tags: matlab, matrix, data-modeling

I am using the `frd` function to get a frequency response of several systems at discrete reduced frequencies. I am having issues with setting a range of frequencies instead of manually inputting one by one and looking at the response (Error: Matrix dimensions must agree). Also, after inputting the range of frequencies and getting 2x2 response matrices, how can I extract each element of the matrices and store them in a separate array so I can use the bode plot at the specified range of reduced frequencies?

Below is my code:

```
%Theodorsen's function at discrete reduced frequencies
k = 10e-20:0.01:10; %discrete reduced frequency range
Ck = (besselh(1,2,k))./(besselh(1,2,k)+1i*besselh(0,2,k)); %Bessel function

%2x2 Matrices
A=[0.8132  -0.1008; -0.0725  2.0518]; 
B=Ck*[7.623  57.15; -8.233  -57.157]; 
C=Ck*[1865  1473.14; -1119  11907.48]; 

%Input Matrix
D=[-1243.028; -2386.614];

%FRD function
sys1=frd(A,k)
sys2=frd(B,k)
sys3=frd(C,k)

%bode(sys1)
%bode(sys2)
%bode(sys3)
```

Comment: What is 'Abar', 'Bbar' & 'Cbar'?

Comment: Sorry, it should be A,B and C

Comment: Can you explain about the frequency response? How can you get a 2*2 matrix as a response of such input frequency?

Comment: If you replace the k range I have above with k=0.1, you will see the response output as a 2x2 matrix. I believe it's because I have a MIMO system. So, Instead of specifying discrete frequency manually I would like to do a range of frequencies and look at their responses